# Usage of "vermögen"

Tags: verb, usage

How do I use the verb *vermögen*? In my dictionary it functions like the modal verb *können*.

> Ich vermag es, mit meiner Freundin Jana nach Mallorca zu fliegen.

Can I remove the *es* and still retain the same meaning?

Comment: Sorry but it seems that your dictionary is from 1800. "vermögen" is (again) too old fashioned !

Comment: Ich bin altmodisch hihi

Comment: @Andri Das Nomen *Vermögen* aber nicht, oder?

Comment: @c.p. Nein, das Nomen nicht ;)

Comment: Note that it does actually not function like "können". Because it uses "zu". It just means the same.

Comment: In fact I would *prefer* to remove the "es". In this case the comma may be dropped as "vermögen" then acts like an auxiliary.

Comment: @c.p. The Noun, "Das UNvermögen" is still in usage today, expressing "the INability to do sth."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can abolish the *es*.
Example: *"Wer vermag mich zu töten?"* (from an old fashioned german fairytale)